# Under which circumstances can the Intent data be null for In-App Billing?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have implemented some in-app purchase in one of my game. The whole process normally work well and a few people have successfully purchased items.

However, looking at the online log of the game, there are a bunch of errors coming from the `handleActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` function because the `Intent data` is **null**.

So, under which circumstance can the intent data be null? Google's documentation doesn't go into any details on this.

Answer (score 5):

I've been CONSTANTLY receiving null intent data until I removed android:launchMode="singleInstance" attribute of the activity in the manifest.
Now I seemingly always receive an intent object.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I had in-app billing setup in a fragment. onActivityResult returned Intent data null and consequently it was null in handleActivityResult. Moving in-app billing to an activity solved the problem for me.